# Can't log out of Facebook

Tags: facebook, security

For two days, we have not been able to log out of our Facebook account. If we cannot log out the normal way, how can we do this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't log out the normal way. What happens? Can you describe in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Change your password.  After you change your password Facebook will ask you if you want all other devices to log out.  Answer YES to this. I suspect that another account is maintaining the login.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is you can check **Where You're Logged In** section under [Security Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security), it shows list of devices and browsers that have been used to log in to your Facebook account recently. You can end any session by clicking **End Activity**.

[Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/211990645501187) says:

> To log out of Facebook on another computer, phone or tablet:
>
> 1. Go to your [Security Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security).
> 2. Click on the **Where You're Logged In** section.
> 3. Find the session you want to end and click **End Activity**.
>
> Clicking **End Activity** will immediately log you off of Facebook on that computer, phone or tablet.